# MySQL - Query All users WITHOUT an appointment

Tags: sql, mysql, database

If I have two tables: Users and Appointments. How would I query the db to find something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (none of: appointments.user = user.id)
```

I am assuming I would need some type of join with the appointments table, just not sure where to start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users 
LEFT JOIN Appointments ON Users.UserID=Appointments.UserID
WHERE Appointments.UserID is null
```

Comment: Except of course, never use select * especially when you have a join.

Comment: Granted, only formed it that way because the OP didn't indicate which fields he needed in the query.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id NOT IN (SELECT user FROM appointments)
```