# MySQL find authors without posts (one-to-many relationship)

Tags: sql, mysql

I've a MySQL problem:

I've two tables (posts and authors) in a one to many relationship (since each post is written by an author and an author can write multiple posts).

So here are the tables:

Authors: id:BIGINT, name:VARCHAR(255)
Posts: id:BIGINT, author_id:BIGINT, body:TEXT.

How can I retrieve all the authors with no posts?

What I've been trying to do is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Authors 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT author_id 
                 FROM Posts 
                 GROUP BY author_id);
```

But it's taking ages!!!

In the two tables there are 300,000 Authors and 1,000,000 Posts!

Any quicker way?

Thanks guys!

Comment: LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is equivalent to NOT IN in MySQL: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this question:
 [MySQL - Query All users WITHOUT an appointment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545436/mysql-query-all-users-without-an-appointment/1545448#1545448)

The answer should be the same.

Also, make sure you have indexes on ID and Author_ID.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM Authors
LEFT JOIN Posts ON (Authors.id = Posts.author_id)
WHERE Posts.author_id IS NULL
```

credit to @john for the first correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
SELECT * FROM Authors a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM Posts p
                  WHERE p.author_id=a.id)
```